# Kubernetes Docker Multi Node Setup issues

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've been attempting to follow the instructions listed in:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.md#starting-the-kubernetes-master

but the apiServer won't stay up, it exits with code 255 almost immediately, the last thing in the logs for the container is:

`F0222 21:45:10.776761       1 server.go:319] Invalid Authentication Config: open /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt: no such file or directory`

I've tried both 1.2.0-alpha.7 and 1.1.2 version of the docker container with:

`sudo docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --privileged=true \
    --pid=host \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v1.1.2 \
    /hyperkube kubelet \
        --allow-privileged=true \
        --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
        --v=2 \
        --address=0.0.0.0 \
        --enable-server \
        --hostname-override=127.0.0.1 \
        --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi \
        --containerized \
        --cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 \
        --cluster-domain=cluster.local`

Only thing I can find, suggested openssl as a dependency, but I've installed that and I'm still getting the error.   It seems to suggest I'm missing a certificate, but I cant find any documentation on it - any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this doc is not 100% and some default variables still require certificates. Try to [generate certificates](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/authentication.md#creating-certificates) manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have also met this problem, you can docker inspect api server, check /srv/kebernetes mount folder, then create ca.key as

```
 openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
 openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -subj "/CN=${MASTER_IP}" -days 10000 -out ca.crt
```

and I have also create two empty files: basic_auth.csv and known_tokens.csv then api server docker start success.